# How to start implementing your own computer?

Tags: soldering, integrated-circuit, raspberry-pi, development

**The question**

As a first step I need to select a circuit board, CPU & RAM/ROM chips and I/O connectors. How do I select a board that can interconnect all these components? Perhaps you could give examples of a full configuration (board and chip models). What type of board would you recommend for a beginner (solderless, stripboard, PCB, ...) ?

Project Outcome: create a motherboard by myself to which I could connect a monitor and a keyboard and the monitor would display the keys I've typed. An additional extension would be receiving and sending data from a network interface.

**Question background**

I have a fairly decent background in software development. However I would like to start doing some hardware projects in my spare time.

I've been looking around on the internet for materials to understand how programs are executed on hardware. Two great resources I've found are the http://nand2tetris.org/ which I am currently undergoing and the raspberrypi motherboard which seems like a simple hardware platform to write your first OS. Given the understanding I can get about the basic workings of operating systems from those resources I would like to start to assemble my own motherboard using standard ICs and write programs for it.

Could you give some initial pointers on where to look for information regarding such kind of projects? In particular I have no idea which ICs would make up a working computer, which kind of board to use to assemble them, how to create the circuits between the ICs. Any kind of information on those basic things would be useful to get me started.

UPDATE:

Since the question seems to be considered vague (how else it could be if you need some kick-start information on an unknown topic) I would like to emphasize that I know programming (Java, C/C++, Python, Assembler x86), i've also done some projects in tools like OrCAD etc. The problems I am struggling with are:

I've never learned the basics for working with physical components

I have little knowledge in components other than general purpose CPU and RAM/ROM chips and how they interconnect with CPU and memory chips in order to make a working computer (the clock, power supply unit, keyboard/monitor/network interface units)

So given all this I need some pointer to resources that contain step-by-step instructions on buying the necessary components and assembling them into a working mini computer. An example of such a resource is the one given by Alfred Centauri in the comments below. [[A Homebuilt Z-80 Computer](http://cpuville.com/Z80.htm)].

Comment: Your main decision is going to be if you want to use an off-the-shelf microprocessor, or implement your own CPU in an FPGA (or if you feel like spending a year of evenings wiring, discrete TTL).  Raspberry pi is a bit of a red herring given its extreme complexity, part of which is unreleased to the public.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to learn the low-level details about how computers work, or are you more interested in building useful things that incorporate computers?

Comment: @DaveTweed actually both, but after I acquire a better understand of the first issue I'd like to focus on the building part.

Comment: @ChrisStratton my goal is not to build a CPU but rather to assemble a CPU with other ICs and I/O interface ports into a working computer.

Comment: @Eugen you will have to decide what level of parts you want to use - you can use a fairly discrete microcprocessor which requires memory and I/O interfaces in separate packages, or you can use a microcontroller or stacked system-on-chip which integrates those in a single package and may need only a few passives and a voltage regulator to run.

Comment: Could you recommend some chip models? Or even better some starter's kit?

Comment: z80?  atmega328?  stm32f103?  It all depends on what part of the project you want to focus your effort on, and what part you want to just work out of the box.

Comment: OK, take a look at this:  http://cpuville.com/Z80.htm  Is this the type of project you're thinking about?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I've skimmed through the website and the book and it seems the type of project I am looking for. However I noticed the computer being built is not interfacing with any I/O device. Anyway, thank you for sharing the resource !

Comment: The screen (and to a lesser extent, keyboard) will greatly increase the amount of work.  Consider separating the problem into building a computer for use with a serial terminal, and perhaps building a serial terminal (for example in an FPGA) that drives an LCD -or you can use a PC with a terminal program.

Comment: @ChrisStratton How to determine/search for a board that has the necessary wiring for connecting a CPU with I/O devices? As far as I understand boards come with a predefined wiring in which you could only solder a specific set of chip models, am I right?

Comment: I think this can be re-opened with a few edits to narrow the focus: what are good techniques for wiring components together -- how do take connectors for a monitor, keyboard, memory, etc, and wire them all together? (solderless breadboard? stripboard? custom PCB?) What sort of off-the-shelf processor is appropriate for someone who wants to learn about electronics and thinks putting some simple images on a monitor would be educational? (Parallax Propeller?)

Comment: Today found 2 resources. Although these guys implemented much more than I want to do it might be useful for other users looking at this question: [a PC](http://homebrewcpu.com/) done by Bill Buzbee. [This one](http://ve2cuy.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/mini-i86-dos-machine/) looks way too complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to do this, I suggest looking at old processors; something of the 6502 or 8080 vintage. In those days, you could take a cpu and some external chips and assemble a working - if limited - computer. Newer processors are much more exacting and challenging to work with.

Note that this is huge undertaking; do a search for the apple 1 schematic, and you'll get some idea of what it will take. Then you get to start writing software for it, and you'll get to do at least some of it in assembly.

If you're actually trying to get things done, the current crop of microcontrollers are *so* much easier to use; you can write in C/C++, they have great built-in capabilities, and they're cheap.